# More Input Methods for Google Card board VR World on Android?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

Is there any hardware available by which we can get more control in VR world on Android in addition to Magnet Card board button? 
For example some bluetooth  joystick/Remote/mouse or any other way to use other android device as Input Source.

Kindly share if  somebody tried.

Answer (score 0):

There are many input devices compatibile with android.

The most basic controls are traditional keyboards or game pads plugged in via an OTG cable. This is also the cheapest option, and easiest to obtain for the consumer.

There are also bluetooth pads compatibile with android.

You can also try to use Wiimotes, but the support and libraries arent really that mature, at least among those that I tried.